# How to set up associations for accepting one proposal in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am developing a feature in a Rails app that allows `users` to create `projects`. Then, other users can create `proposals`. Finally, the user that created the project can accept one of the proposals as the accepted proposal.

**What is the best way to allow the user that created the project (the manager) to select one of the proposals as the accepted proposal?**

The models are set up like this:

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :proposals
end
```

Project model

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :proposals
end
```

Proposal model

```
class Proposal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

At first, I thought about an "accepted" boolean in the proposal table that would allow the user to mark the boolean as true to make the proposal "accepted". But this could lead to problems like some projects having more than one accepted proposal. It isn't the correct way to do this.

So, how should I set up an acceptance model that allows the manager to select and de-select a proposal as the one and only "accepted" proposal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be 100% sure that no project can have more than one accepted proposal, then you can set it up with an additional relation. You would also need another relation inside Proposal

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :accepted_proposal, class_name: 'Proposal', inverse_of: :accepted_for, optional: true
end

class Proposal < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :accepted_for, class_name: 'Project', inverse_of: :accepted_proposal
end
```

You can also validate uniqueness only for accepted proposals, but I think you can't have a database unique index for this

```
class Proposal < ApplicationRecord
  validates :project_id, :uniqueness, if: Proc.new { |proposal| proposal.accepted }
end
```

Comment: This solution prevents the user (manager) from creating new projects because it will look for the project's accepted_proposal which it will not have.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I always forget to set `optional: true`. I updated the answer. In case you're using an old version of rails (< 5) it's `required: false`